# i have this exception when execution of Entity Manager Factory creation statement

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, jpa-2.0, google-cloud-datastore

when execute this java code,that make select from datastore ,an exception was appeared due to first row,so how i can solve this exception?
exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
```

code:

```
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
try {
    EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
    EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
    javax.persistence.Query query = entitymanager.createQuery("Select u from test u");
    List<test> list = (List<test>) query.getResultList();
    out.print(list.size());
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e.toString());
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

persistence.xml:

```html
 <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
  <provider>
  org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProviderImpl
</provider>
  <properties>
   <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
   <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true" />
   <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Could you try `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace( out ); }` - perhaps there is a nested exception?

Comment: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl

Comment: Caused by: org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidClassMetaDataException: Class s.follows has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.

Comment: @Kenney i have class follows in my project in package s

Comment: Thanks - It is allright (and even better) to update the question with the stacktraces. According to [this](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/primary_key.html), when you use ApplicationIdentity you need to define a primary key. Could you update the question with the `s.follows` class?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234032/i-was-deployed-my-app-into-gae-but-i-have-this-exception-when-execution

Answer (score 1):

As the Exception that you posted in the Comments (!) says

```
org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidClassMetaDataException: Class s.follows has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.
```

Yet you don't post this class (why?! don't you think people may want to see it, when it is what the exception is about?).

Solution : mark a field as `@Id` just like all JPA docs say to.